# Code reviews in Azure dev ops without feature branches

Tags: azure-devops

We have come from a background of using Subversion and everyone checking into the same branch

Now we are using Azure devops, using individual feature branches. Code reviews are much easier, but we are hitting all the classic issues with feature branches, nightmare merges and we are reluctant to refactor

We can't make the feature branches shorter in length and still have a useful piece of work

What's the middle ground? In an ideal world you could check into the same branch, tag the checkins and still get azure to produce a single body of code to review at the end

I'm sure this is a very common problem, how could we improve the process?

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC for source control?

Comment: We're using Git

Answer (score 1):

First, I challenge the statement *We can't make the feature branches shorter in length*. You absolutely can. You need to work in smaller user stories, isolate in-progress features behind feature toggles, and progressively review and merge as the larger feature is implemented.

That said, if you want to continue to maintain long-lived feature branches (which I recommend against), the solution is **more branches**. You branch from your feature branch for a more narrowly scoped subset of the work, and when that subset is complete, review and merge it into the feature branch. When the feature is complete, merge it to your main/master branch.